# How to implement Firebase on Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, dsl, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm new to Kotlin DSL. I'm trying to migrate my current project to Kotlin DSL. But I have one problem, I can't import firebase analytics and firebase crashlytics in my code.

Here how I implemented firebase on project : gradle.build.kts (app)

```
plugins {
...
id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf") }


dependencies{ 
...
val firebaseVersion = "17.3.0"
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseVersion")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$firebaseVersion")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:$firebaseVersion")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.10")}
```

gradle.build.kts ( level project )

```
dependencies {
classpath(Gradle.firebaseCrash)
    classpath(Gradle.firebasePlugin) }
```

//this is on buildSrc module
const val firebaseCrash = "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0"
const val firebasePlugin ="com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1"

After building session, then an error comes from my class

[Error Code Detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGF63.png)

anyone knows how to implementing it in a good way? I've searched for other resources but I still got nothing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using [ParametersBuilder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/analytics/ktx/ParametersBuilder) which is a part of `firebase-analytics-ktx` artifact, so you need to include that in your dependencies.

Also, I'd recommend to follow [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-sdks) on how to set up the sdk. In particular the recommended way now is to use bom.